# JW Player 6 plugin not working in Firefox - Drupal

Tags: javascript, firefox, drupal-7

I have installed JW Player 6 plugin in drupal 7. It works fine in IE 8, Safari and Chrome. But it is not working in IE 9,10 and Firefox.  I have used it with the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/jwplayer/jwplayer.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">jwplayer.key="ABCDEFGHIJKLMOPQ";</script>
<div id="myElement">Loading the player...</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    jwplayer("myElement").setup({
        file: "/uploads/myVideo.mp4",
        image: "/uploads/myPoster.jpg"
    });
</script>
```

What can be changed in code to make it work for firefox and IE 9,10 ? Is there any other plugin that works fine for this JW player?

Answer (score 2):

Check out this on playing video: [W3 HTML5 Video](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp)

Here is the browser file type specs:
[image: From w3schools.com]
*From w3schools.com*

Other information I was able to obtain showed that Firefox on Windows XP will unfortunately never be able to play .mp4 video, but Windows Vista and Windows 7 will, as far as Mac OS, people claim it is a patient issue.

I would recommend converting this video to a .ogg format, which will play in Firefox on all systems, then putting logic in the code for Firefox and Opera vs. IE, Chrome, and Safari.

Answer (score 0):

Firefox doesn't accept **codec H264** which many mp4 videos are encoded. Try with an .ogv or .webm to test, or provide a fallback.

Comment: In the default HTML5 player you can set multiple source files so if the browser cannot support try with the next one. I think you can do the same with JW Playe